# Why isn't "Path to project(s)" modifiable?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

In an Azure DevOps build, a .NET Core Test step has a "Path to project(s)" property, which is set to `**/*[Tt]ests/*.csproj`.

Why can't I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's editable if one manually adds a .NET Core build step to a build switched to the "Test" command instead of using the "Test" step from the default .NET Core sequence of build steps.

Answer (score 1):

Because by default this setting will be linked to `**\*.sln`

[image]

You need to unlink it.To do this you have a link at the top right corner called link settings where other links like view yaml and remove can be found nearby.

Click the link settings and unlink the defaullt value of the solution.

[image]